# Rodar o Windows direto da partição no Linux

Tags: linux, windows, emulador

Queria saber se tem um jeito de rodar o Windows que está instalado em uma partição, dentro do Ubuntu, ou outra distrito. Tipo, emulando uma máquina com o Virtualbox, só que em vez de usar um arquivo como HD, usar uma partição onde está instalado o Windows.